# How to copy a file with a new name with parts from original file name?

Tags: batch-file

I have a bunch of files with the name `383DT_SBY_20170420_08_C.ps`, `380_DB_20170421_08_C.ps`, etc.
I am trying to create a script that will automatically copy and rename them to `SBY_20170420_08.ps`, `DB_20170421_08.ps`.

The following script used to work but now it tells me it can't find the file specified.

```
@echo off
T:
cd \PROOFS\out\
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=_ " %%a in ("%1") do set first=%%a&set second=%%b&set third=%%c&set fourth=%%d&set fifth=%%e
copy %1 Renamed\"%second%%third%_%fourth%.ps"
```

Comment: How is this batch file called? What is the first argument referenced with`%1`? I suggest to change `"%1"` to `"%~1"` on __FOR__ command line. Run in a command prompt window `call /?` for help on how to reference arguments of a batch file. Run `for /?` to get help on command __FOR__. Also it would be better to use `copy "%~1" "Renamed\%second%%third%_%fourth%.ps"`, i.e. always enclose source and target completely in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

- test the existence of the file prior trying to copy it.
- if you only need tokens 2 to 4, there is no need to put 1 and 5 into vars
- if a (mapped) drive isn't available the seperate drive change and cd don't work, better use `CD /D` or `Pushd` and check success
- the batch depends on the passed arguments if the arg doesn't match with `*_*_*_*_*.ps` it will  fail
- if the batch shall handle all files with the pattern you need an additional for loop

---

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
CD /D "T:\PROOFS\out\" || pause & goto :Eof
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=_" %%a in ("%~1") do If exist "%~1" (
  copy "%~1" "Renamed\%%a_%%b_%%c%~x1"
) else (
  Echo %~1 doesn*t exist in %CD%
)
```